Modify options for Authentication in a Blazor app with OpenId out of Program.cs
I have a Blazor app configured to authenticate with OpenId (Auth0 in this case). In my Program.cs i have this:
var auth0Domain = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
var auth0ClientId = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth0Domain) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth0ClientId))
{
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = $"https://{auth0Domain}";
        options.ClientId = auth0ClientId;
        //options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/account/callback");
        options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true; //ESTO RESOLVIO EL PROBLMA DE MESSAGE.STATE NULL
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
    });
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });
}

And in my AccountController I have this:
[HttpGet]
public async Task ExternalLogin(string redirectUrl)
{
    string callbackUrl = redirectUrl + "account/callback";
    //Console.WriteLine(callbackUrl);
    var authenticationProperties = new LoginAuthenticationPropertiesBuilder()
                .WithRedirectUri(callbackUrl)
                .Build();

    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
}

What I want is to be able to modify the Domain and the ClientId before do the ChallengeAsync. My App needs to handle differents authentication ways dependending of the user that is trying to authenticate. My users are in a database where I store the auth type they use.
I have been searching for a way to do the OpenId configuration out of my Program.cs

Sure you could modify by using options monitor like following:
[HttpGet]
public async Task ExternalLogin(string redirectUrl)
{
    ...

    var serviceProvider = HttpContext.RequestServices;
    var optionsMonitor = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<OpenIdConnectOptions>>();
    var OIDC_options = optionsMonitor.Get(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme);

    OIDC_options.ClientId = "new id";

    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
}

-----------------------update----------------------
There are some options that are implicit configured. Such as when you first set
options.Authority = "http://10.96.5.5:8080/realms/master/";

The MetadataAddress is automatically configured by the authority.
options.MetadataAddress = "http://10.96.5.5:8080/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration"

But when you use options monitor to change the authoriry, the metadataAddress doesn't change together. You have to change it manually. Another similar configuration is the validAudience. So I suggest you try adding following when do the modification.
            var OIDC_options = optionsMonitor.Get(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme);

            OIDC_options.Authority = configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
            OIDC_options.MetadataAddress = configuration["Auth0:Domain"]+"/.well-known/openid-configuration";

            OIDC_options.ClientId = configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];          
            OIDC_options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[] { "Auth0:ClientId" };


Thanks for your answer. Please can you provide the rest of the code? How it would look in Program.cs?

@CarlosLopezDurañona no need to register anything about options monitor in program.cs. Just use this code directly.

Sorry, is not working. Can you check the updated code I've posted in my second answer?

The ChallengeAsync is not using the OIDC_options. How will this work?

@CarlosLopezDurañona I have update the answer you could try. When you get OIDC_options from IoptionsMonitor, it is linked to the options in the service container which you initial at program.cs

Still not working even with the update you suggested. The Challenge keeps targeting the https://generic-domain.com I defined in my Program.cs
